# General Solution for classes in which copy constructor using default constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Is there a general wrapper for class fields which upon copying (both initialization and assignment) use default constructor (or other constructor) instead of actually copying the data?

**One (non- satisfactory) solution:**

In the containing class implement explicitly the copy constructor:

```
class Containing {
public:
    Containing(const Containing &other) : o1(), o2(other.o2) {};
private:
    Object o1;
    OtherObject o2;
};
```

**Downside:**
I have to explicitly define the copy c'tor.

**Second (non- satisfactory) solution:**

Similarly to `std::unique_ptr` I can implementing a pointer which upon copying just uses the default constructor. Example:

```
template<typename T>
class copyable_unique_ptr {
public:
    copyable_unique_ptr(const copyable_unique_ptr<T> &other) : p = make_shared<T>() {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> p;
};
```

**Downside:**
Using dynamically allocated memory when it's unnecessarily.

**Third solution (suggested through comments) :**

The same as second solution but without using pointers and dynamic memory:

```
template<typename T>
class defaultly_copyable_wrapper {
public:
    defaultly_copyable_wrapper(T &o) : o(o) {}
    defaultly_copyable_wrapper(const defaultly_copyable_wrapper<T> &other) : o() {}
private:
    T o;
};
```

So far, this looks as the optimal solution.

Is there a better solution (or a standardized third solution)? Isn't there common use-case for that?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is what I'm trying to achieve. The first solution clearly doesn't achieve that and hence non- satisfactory

Comment: the "second" solution doesn't make any sense, memory allocation type has nothing to do with this. trying to copy a `unique_ptr` gives a compilation error, not any sort of default construction

Comment: There isn't a standard wrapper for this, you could make one, e.g. `SpecialCopy<Object> o1;`

Comment: "I can implementing a pointer which upon copying just uses the default constructor" - why a *pointer*?